# Scale absolute positioned points on a picture map

Tags: css, media-queries, scale

positioned POIs on a picture map as follows : http://sg-cms.azurewebsites.net/opespe/travel/

I have tried to apply CSS scale and re-positioning in media queries but I can't manage to have a good result. The points are never on the right place.

Do you think it is possible with this method? If not what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning it with percents - I think it's right direction. Berlin is near top: 21%, left: 49% and scales quite properly at my machine (firefox). Although there is a weird jump near forth zoom level (4 x CTRL + +).